# Sweet rice recipe help? Panama cook book recipe

Tags: rice

This is from my vague Panama cookbook for "Sweet Rice." It's a side dish, not dessert.

Ingredients:

```
- 4 or 5 coconuts (Google says 1 coconut is 1 or 2 cups of coconut milk)    
- 1/2 pound of ginger (?)
- 1 box of raisins (my guess is 2 cups since I'll be making 4 cups of rice)
- 1 pound of rice (Google says 2 cups uncooked)
- Cinnamon to taste (?)
- Clove to taste (?)
- Salt to taste
- Light brown sugar (?)
- White sugar (?)
```

Please help me with "to taste" directions. I can't cook, I need specifics.
1/2 pound of ground ginger? How many thumbs would you use?
Cinnamon and clove to taste? How many ml?
And what's your guess on the amounts of sugar?

These directions sound so easy but I can't guess on these amounts myself. Appreciate any help, thanks.

[image]

Comment: There is a reason your cookbook gives you the amounts in weight. "How many ml?" We don't know. Volume is a bad measurement in cooking, worse in baking. Also, "to taste" means exactly that - keep adding until you like it.

Comment: @rumtscho Volume of spices is not really that crazy; it's not exact but recipes also aren't sensitive, and people are much more likely to have measuring spoons than a tenth-gram precision kitchen scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I start by saying... You need a new cook book...

Regarding the question.
**For my taste**

- 1tsp cloves
- 2tsp cinnamon
- 2tbsp brown sugar
- 1tbsp white sugar
- 3 Inches of Ginger

How many people are you cooking for because as a "Side Dish" this seems to make a huge amount of product.
As I said this is how I would do it to my taste but It's not something I've ever eaten before and I **HATE** the taste of cloves.

Comment: 3 people? Thanks for your taste! I would have had no idea.  I'm not good at tasting something and knowing how much more to add.  That's what a chef can do! I know, this cookbook really sucks. I should just keep it as a Panama souvenir and leave it as that!